# How Secure Is Too Secure in OAuth 2.0?

Tags: python, django, api, security, oauth-2.0

Background: I am currently on a team responsible for building an API for University College, London.

I am responsible for building an implementation of OAuth which sits on top of Shibboleth that we can provide to our users. In order to keep it as secure as possible (we are going to be providing student data, so we can't take any risks here), I have implemented a nonce parameter along with a `client_secret_proof` parameter (the `appsecret_proof` that is described at sakurity.com/oauth).

The difference is that in my implementation a request is made to a nonce endpoint and then this nonce value is concatenated onto the user's token then run through the HMAC algorithm so that the `client_secret_proof` parameter cannot be replayed.

The question here is that my PM thinks this extra protection is unnecessary and just terrible for Developer Experience, but I want to try and make it as difficult as possible to MITM the connection and do as much as I can to prevent the leaking of client secrets by sloppy programming on the part of our student developers. Am I wasting my time in toughening up OAuth here, or is OAuth 2.0 inherently weak when it comes to preventing certain types of attacks? My main concern is developers not properly validating HTTPS certificates which would render the protection already present in HTTPS moot.

Thank you so much for any thoughts you have on this! We don't want to offer a terrible Developer Experience, but we don't want to leave any attack vectors unconsidered either.

Implementation of protection: https://github.com/uclapi/uclapi/blob/OAuth/backend/uclapi/oauth/decorators.py#L86

Client library: https://github.com/uclapi/django-uclapi-oauth/blob/master/apidemo/uclapi/views.py

Comment: It feels like this question would be better asked at [Cryptography Stack Exchange](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/). I'm not sure folks on this site will read the RFC and then evaluate the security properties and risk of your enhancements. Also see [Developer Quits OAuth 2.0 Spec, Calls It ‘a Bad Protocol’](https://www.wired.com/2012/07/developer-quits-oauth-2-0-spec-calls-it-a-bad-protocol/).

Comment: @jww thanks for this. I found that article and it gave me some validation that I was doing the right things to try and secure the protocol, but perhaps it is just inherently broken. Is it okay to just cross-post to crypto?

Comment: You can flag the question and ask the moderators move it so you don't have to delete it on one site and create it on another site. For whatever reasons, the Stack Exchange network does not allow you to migrate it yourself. Also see [Author initiated migration to other SE sites?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254851)

Comment: Based on what I know of OAuth, including OAuth 1.1 and the criticisms of OAuth 2.0, I would consider using OAuth 1.1 (not 1.0) as a starting point. I don't know how painful it might be in real life, however.

Answer (score 1):

Although you fail to mention what type of OAuth 2.0 client you are using? (SPA, Web App or ??). I would NOT us anything but OAuth 2.0 or OpenID Connect. (as OpenID Connect uses JWTs which can be signed and encrypted.)

[Developer Quits OAuth 2.0 Spec, Calls It ‘a Bad Protocol](https://www.wired.com/2012/07/developer-quits-oauth-2-0-spec-calls-it-a-bad-protocol/)’ was in 2012 and things have needless to say progressed a lot since then.

Most of the weaknesses have resulted from implementations weaknesses as pointed out by [A Comprehensive Formal Security Analysis of OAuth 2.0](https://infsec.uni-trier.de/people/publications/paper/FettKuestersSchmitz-CCS-2016.pdf) (done in 2016)

Even since 2016, there are several enhancements to OAuth 2.0 and OpenID connect from a [Security Considerations](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/OAuth%202.0%20Security%20Considerations) perspective.

And in today's Cyber Environment just what is "Too Secure" when handling sensitive information where a breach could cause damage to an Organization's reputation?

Comment: plus rollling your own will always end up, at some point, being less secure

Comment: Ah, sorry, should have clarified. The API is built on Django and we expect developers to use us as an an IdP that redirects to their chosen callback URL, from which they can exchange a code GET parameter for a token.

Our PM is generally happy with OAuth 2.0 as a standard since GitHub, Slack, etc. use it, but 1.1 has always seemed more secure, but I'm not sure if that's because of a greater number of parameters.

Comment: I suppose the question should have been better phrased if I had asked whether each of my extra security features (e.g. nonces and HMAC proofs of the client secret) are actually necessary, and worth the trade off in terms of developer experience? Assuming certificate validation is implemented correctly on the client side, I'd assume not, but if it is not done correctly then a client secret could be easily MITM'd.